# protoc-gen-go-rpc: program not found or is not executable - Where do I get protoc-gen-go-rpc?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, grpc-go

We are using protoc-gen-go v2 (v2 is google.golang.org/protobuf, v1 is github.com/golang/protobuf)

When we are trying to compile our gRPC services, it tells us that `plugins` is not supported anymore and we should instead use `--go-grpc_out`:

```
$ protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: plugins are not supported; use 'protoc --go-grpc_out=...' to generate gRPC
```

And when using `--go-grpc_out`, it is telling us we need the `protoc-gen-go-rpc`:

```
$ protoc --go-rpc_out=. *.proto
protoc-gen-go-rpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
```

Where do you find, or how do you install `protoc-gen-go-rpc`?

Update: We also just found this post on Reddit for additional information
https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/fe3a4k/documentation_on_getting_grpc_working_with_the/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `protoc-gen-go v2`, because the latest `protobuf` tag I can see is `v1.4`.

Here is the example how we call `protoc` to generate source code for sevice called `crab` that has no external dependencies (e.g. no external protofile imports). The only binary dependency is `protoc-gen-go`

```sh
protoc -I $(pwd) -I /home/isaev/go/src \
 $(pwd)/crab/error_codes.proto \
 $(pwd)/crab/goproxy.proto \
 $(pwd)/crab/crab.proto \
 --go_out=plugins=grpc:/tmp/crab
```

Comment: Hey, yes. Since you use "plugins", you are still using an old version of protocol-gen-go

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0#v1.20-grpc-support